# Retrieve number of samples allocated by driver

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, multisampling

I am working on application in which i am using multisampled textures. Now, i want to retrieve number of actual samples allocated by driver. for e.g. when my application asks for a 1X multisampled texture then the driver legally allocates a 2X multisampled texture how can i retrieve this number legally allocated by driver? I have searched corresponding argument with glGet but did not find the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of samples allocated for a particular texture by [querying `GL_TEXTURE_SAMPLES` from `glGetTexLevelParameteriv`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetTexLevelParameter). And no, I didn't insert that into the page just now. Pay no attention to [the edit history of that page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki_132/index.php?title=GLAPI/glGetTexLevelParameter&diff=8946&oldid=8945); it's always been there.